How get attributes of function into this function?
When i get the attributes of my function. If i getName(), i've a path as name Base\Service\Client\filters .. How i can only get filters as name ?
#[filters(['email', 'emailVerified', 'enabled', 'firstName', 'lastName', 'q', 'username'])]
public function getUsers(?array $filter = null): iterable
{
    $method = new \ReflectionMethod($this, 'getUsers');
    $attributes = $method->getAttributes();

    $f = [];
    foreach ($attributes as $reflection) {
        $f[$reflection->getName()] =  $reflection->getArguments();
    }

    dd($f);

OUPUT:
[
    'Base\Service\Client\filters' => [ /** I'ld filter, like thats i can $method->getAttributes('filters)
        (int) 0 => [
            (int) 0 => 'email',
            (int) 1 => 'emailVerified',
            (int) 2 => 'enabled',
            (int) 3 => 'firstName',
            (int) 4 => 'lastName',
            (int) 5 => 'q',
            (int) 6 => 'username',
        ],
    ],
]


I'm not certain what your question is. The getAttributes() method supports passing in the specific attribute you want: https://3v4l.org/fjTMpE#v8.3.9

Or, is your question how to get the specific instance? https://3v4l.org/IR5la#v8.3.9

OK, thank's Chris.
If i understand, the attributes need to be link at a class for be operate ? I though there was only need declare the attributes and read her from Reflection method ..

Try dd($filter) instead of dd($f).

Per the docs: "While not strictly required it is recommended to create an actual class for every attribute." If you just want to call methods from the general ReflectionAttribute class such as getName() and getArguments(), you don't need a class, or if you want to manually parse those. Having a class back the attribute allows you to potentially isolate logic, type the parameters, perform validation, etc.

Attribute names are resolved using the same namespace resolution rules as the names of classes, interfaces, etc:

If the name starts with \, it is a "fully-qualified name", and left as-is
If the name matches, or begins with, a name you have imported or aliased with use, that name is substituted
Else, the name is interpreted as relative to the current namespace

Note that all this happens independently of actually loading any code. If the current namespace is Base\Service\Client, and there are no relevant use statements, #[filters(['whatever'])] and new filters(['whatever']); will be expanded to #[Base\Service\Client\filters(['whatever'])] and new Base\Service\Client\filters(['whatever']); before PHP has any idea whether that class actually exists.
Even if you never ask for the attribute as an object, you will get its fully-qualified name.
So you can either:

Fully-qualify the name as being in the global namespace: #[\filters(['whatever'])]
Pick a namespace (so you know it won't collide with some other use of the name "filters"), and add a use statement, e.g. use Mbtm\Attributes\filters; Then you can write #[filters(['whatever'])] and getName() will return 'Mbtm\Attributes\filters'.

